# How to perform Oracle sql order by with captial case string

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, sql-order-by

I need to order my table rows as like below, They have a mix of full capital or First letter capital strings.

```
NewYork
Santa Clara
San (w) Jose
ATLANTA
LONDON
```

I tried using following query

```
select city_name from city
order by
case
when city_name=upper(city_name) then 2
else 1 end
```

I get ordered rows, but in random like the one below,

```
San (w) Jose
NewYork 
Santa Clara
LONDON
ATLANTA
```

Any help to sort the rows with Capital string first is much appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: In your sample results, the cities are mixed case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you want to order by city after you order by the case.  You can add this to the `order by`:

```
select city_name
from city
order by (case when city_name=upper(city_name) then 2 else 1 end),
         city_name;
```

Oracle is case-sensitive by default so this should work.